# Get the value of the related input on hovering a label using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button, hover

I am trying to get the value of the input when a mouse hovers on a label. How can I deal with this?

HTML

```
       <label class="target">
         <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hi" class="greeting">
         <span>Hi</span>
       </label>
      <label class="target">
         <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hello" class="greeting">
         <span>Hello</span>
       </label>
```

Radio buttons are hidden, so when the mouse is over the label, it is hovering the span element.

I am only getting the first element, 'hi' in jQuery.

```
$('.target').hover(function() {
   alert('hovering: ' + $('.greeting').val());
})
```

I want to show the each value.

Comment: what you tried so far give the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('label').hover(function(){
alert($(this).find('input').val())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="target">
  <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hi" class="greeting">
  <span>Hi</span>
</label>
<label class="target">
  <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hello" class="greeting">
  <span>Hello</span>
</label>
```

use `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

Use an event handler and get input element within the context.

```js
$('.target').hover(function() {
  console.log($('input', this).val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="target">
  <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hi" class="greeting">
  <span>Hi</span>
</label>
<label class="target">
  <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hello" class="greeting">
  <span>Hello</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside hover function `$('.greeting').val()` will fetch value of first input box regardless hover on any label. So to fetch value of respected input have to use `$(this).find('.greeting').val()`

```js
$('.target').hover(function() {
   alert('hovering: ' + $(this).find('.greeting').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="target">
  <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hi" class="greeting">
  <span>Hi</span>
</label>
<label class="target">
  <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hello" class="greeting">
  <span>Hello</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("label").on("mouseover", function(e) {
  alert($(this).find("input").val());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="target">
     <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hi" class="greeting">
     <span>Hi</span>
</label>
<label class="target">
     <input type="radio" name="hello" value="hello" class="greeting">
     <span>Hello</span>
</label>
```