# select option on press of key up/down using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a onchange event on the select dropdown. so whenever any option clicked, onclick event fired and then further stuff take place. It is working fine.

I want to do the same when we move on options using keyboard up and down arrow keys. That means whenever any option highlighted by pressing key up/down, it should get selected and onchange event should fire.

Here is the HTML code :

```
<select name="list_numbers" id="list_numbers" onchange="javascript:fireOnChangeEvent(this);">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", event => { 
    if((event.keyCode == 38 || event.keyCode == 40)) {
        console.log("up or down key pressed");
    }

});
```

The above code works well and detect event when Up and down key pressed without opening of the dropdown. but, when the dropdown is opened and if I navigate the options using up and down keys then the keydown event not tracked.

so need some help on firing onchange event when options are just navigated and not hit enter using keyboard up and down key.

Note: I have tried some solutions for similar questions, but didn't work for me.

Comment: `<option>` elements don't support events cross browser so only way is use enter to make the change from keyboard. For more advanced interactions you need a select replacement script

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please explain further on replacement script?

Comment: try using hover, get the value using hover and use ajax for rest
[chek this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41562349/get-the-value-of-the-related-input-on-hovering-a-label-using-jquery)